# .Htaccess - Get new parameter in mini MVC PHP framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

I have google this, but could not find anything and I cant figure it out by myself.

I have created a mini MVC PHP Freamework and have this .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Normally I get the url from a bootstrap and gets the model and controller to the current url.

But what if I have a new GET like:

```
if (isset($_GET['topic']))
{
 // echo  the forum topic.
}
```

Right now the url is: `http://domain.com/mvc/forum/topic?topic=this-is-the-topic-title-url`

How can I rewrite this in the htaccess to `http://domain.com/mvc/forum/topic/this-is-the-topic-title-url`?

Answer (score 0):

You could...

1. either analyse your `$_GET['url']` parameter and modify your `$_GET` array dynamically inside your program, *or*
2. work with multiple rewrite rules:

   ```
   # Put this rewrite rule first, because it is more specific, and the
   # second rule will catch anything.
   RewriteRule ^(.+/topic)/(.+)$ index.php?url=$1&topic=$2 [QSA,L]
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
   ```

Comment: It seems to not be working. The url is still the same and the html and css is not being loaded, so it is clean text. Could it be something with my Bootstrap?

Comment: Update: The rewrite works, but the css and images files dont work. I have used absolute path.

Comment: Do you still use the `RewriteCond` statements from your original question? They are still needed to ensure that the rewrite rules do not apply to existing files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the css file with:

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```